# New Custom Error element in Record Triggered Flows Does Not Stop Processing and Does Not Show Error Message

Tags: visual-workflow, error-messages, recordtriggeredflow

[Resubmitted with supporting documentation]

I am utilizing the new (Winter '24) "Custom Error" element that is now available in Record Triggered Flows.

While debugging the flow (changing the status to Delegated), the "Custom Error" element is executed and then the flow is ended.
[image: Debugging the Flow]

When I test changing the status to Delegated using the UI, the action completes successfully when it should not.
[image: Testing Using the UI]

Here's the log generated while changing the status to Delegated using the UI

```
10:39:24.36 (36429582)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D3R0000008gqs|3003R0000008OI5|3013R000000HRsY

10:39:24.36 (36459720)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|XXXX Assignment Before Update

10:39:24.36 (36606948)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1

10:39:24.36 (36629639)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|XXXX Assignment Before Update

10:39:24.36 (37848067)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|$Record|{Id=a043R000003MEiCQAW, OwnerId=00Gt000000175e1EAA, IsDeleted=false, Name=XXXX-02699, RecordTypeId=012t0000000CoK1AAK, CreatedDate=2023-12-08 18:28:21, CreatedById=0053R000002v0g7QAA, LastModifiedDate=2023-12-08 18:39:15, LastModifiedById=005j000000D0eJFAAZ, SystemModstamp=2023-12-08 18:39:15, LastActivityDate=null, LastViewedDate=null, LastReferencedDate=null, Absence_Dates__c=null, Agency__c=null, Assigned_To__c=null, Attendee_s__c=null, Author_Name__c=null, BDO_Suborganization__c=Legislative Office, BDO__c=ARB, Body__c=null, Closed_Withdrawn_Date__c=null, Confidential__c=false, Contact_Name__c=null, Department__c=null, Description__c=null, Division__c=null, Document_Number__c=null, Due_Date__c=2023-12-29 00:00:00, Event_City__c=null, Event_End_Date__c=null, Event_Hours__c=null, Event_Location__c=null, Event_Sponsor__c=null, Event_Start_Date__c=null, Event_State__c=California, Event_Title__c=null, Event_Zip_Code__c=null, Excess_Lodging__c=No, Expenses_not_to_Exceed__c=null, Final_Outcome__c=null, Flag_Logged_In_User_Program__c=1.0, Flag_Logged_In_User__c=1.0, Form_of_Original__c=null, Fund__c=null, Governor_s_Office_Number__c=null, Internal_Tracking_ID__c=null, Mission_Critical_Justification__c=null, Mission_Critical_Travel__c=false, My_Assignments__c=false, Originator__c=null, Other__c=false, Phone__c=null, Purpose_of_Attendance__c=null, Received_Date__c=null, Regular_Visit__c=false, Reply_By__c=null, Requested_By__c=null, Signature_Of__c=null, Signed_by__c=null, Status__c=In Progress, Subject__c=XXXX Assignment CLI Validations XXXX Assignment CLI Validations You Cannot Delegate An Assignment That Has No Tasks, Test_Data__c=true, Title__c=null, Total_Estimated_Event_Cost__c=null, Travel_Distance_From_HQ__c=null, Type__c=Controlled Correspondence, Unit__c=null, Urgent__c=false, External_Id__c=null, Check_Assignment_InProgress_WithNoTasks__c=false, Check_Close_Task_In_Progress__c=false, Check_Complete_Task_In_Progress__c=false, Delete_Task_ID__c=null, Validation_Bypass_DateTime__c=1900-01-01 00:00:00, CheckVRBypassed__c=false}

10:39:24.36 (37928871)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed

10:39:24.36 (37958494)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed

10:39:24.36 (37992292)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed

10:39:24.36 (38012453)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|XXXX Assignment Before Update

10:39:24.36 (38028867)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed

10:39:24.36 (38092814)|FLOW_RULE_DETAIL|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_Yes|true|false

10:39:24.36 (38110547)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_Yes|true

10:39:24.36 (38166892)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed|0|0

10:39:24.36 (38181815)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_Closed_or_Withdrawn

10:39:24.36 (38190975)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_Closed_or_Withdrawn

10:39:24.36 (38205158)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_Closed_or_Withdrawn

10:39:24.36 (38216632)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_Closed_or_Withdrawn

10:39:24.36 (38247895)|FLOW_RULE_DETAIL|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_Closed_or_Withdrawn_Yes|false|false

10:39:24.36 (38263647)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_Closed_or_Withdrawn_Yes|false

10:39:24.36 (38296172)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_Closed_or_Withdrawn|0|0

10:39:24.36 (38308515)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowRecordUpdate|Update_Assignment_Closed_Withdrawn_Date_Field_To_Null

10:39:24.36 (38317819)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowRecordUpdate|Update_Assignment_Closed_Withdrawn_Date_Field_To_Null

10:39:24.36 (38329168)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowRecordUpdate|Update_Assignment_Closed_Withdrawn_Date_Field_To_Null

10:39:24.36 (38345779)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowRecordUpdate|Update_Assignment_Closed_Withdrawn_Date_Field_To_Null

10:39:24.36 (38646381)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Update_Assignment_Closed_Withdrawn_Date_Field_To_Null__CONDITIONS_RESULT|true

10:39:24.36 (38652732)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Update_Assignment_Closed_Withdrawn_Date_Field_To_Null|true

10:39:24.36 (38992018)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|$Record|{Id=a043R000003MEiCQAW, OwnerId=00Gt000000175e1EAA, IsDeleted=false, Name=XXXX-02699, RecordTypeId=012t0000000CoK1AAK, CreatedDate=2023-12-08 18:28:21, CreatedById=0053R000002v0g7QAA, LastModifiedDate=2023-12-08 18:39:15, LastModifiedById=005j000000D0eJFAAZ, SystemModstamp=2023-12-08 18:39:15, LastActivityDate=null, LastViewedDate=null, LastReferencedDate=null, Absence_Dates__c=null, Agency__c=null, Assigned_To__c=null, Attendee_s__c=null, Author_Name__c=null, BDO_Suborganization__c=Legislative Office, BDO__c=ARB, Body__c=null, Closed_Withdrawn_Date__c=null, Confidential__c=false, Contact_Name__c=null, Department__c=null, Description__c=null, Division__c=null, Document_Number__c=null, Due_Date__c=2023-12-29 00:00:00, Event_City__c=null, Event_End_Date__c=null, Event_Hours__c=null, Event_Location__c=null, Event_Sponsor__c=null, Event_Start_Date__c=null, Event_State__c=California, Event_Title__c=null, Event_Zip_Code__c=null, Excess_Lodging__c=No, Expenses_not_to_Exceed__c=null, Final_Outcome__c=null, Flag_Logged_In_User_Program__c=1.0, Flag_Logged_In_User__c=1.0, Form_of_Original__c=null, Fund__c=null, Governor_s_Office_Number__c=null, Internal_Tracking_ID__c=null, Mission_Critical_Justification__c=null, Mission_Critical_Travel__c=false, My_Assignments__c=false, Originator__c=null, Other__c=false, Phone__c=null, Purpose_of_Attendance__c=null, Received_Date__c=null, Regular_Visit__c=false, Reply_By__c=null, Requested_By__c=null, Signature_Of__c=null, Signed_by__c=null, Status__c=In Progress, Subject__c=XXXX Assignment CLI Validations XXXX Assignment CLI Validations You Cannot Delegate An Assignment That Has No Tasks, Test_Data__c=true, Title__c=null, Total_Estimated_Event_Cost__c=null, Travel_Distance_From_HQ__c=null, Type__c=Controlled Correspondence, Unit__c=null, Urgent__c=false, External_Id__c=null, Check_Assignment_InProgress_WithNoTasks__c=false, Check_Close_Task_In_Progress__c=false, Check_Complete_Task_In_Progress__c=false, Delete_Task_ID__c=null, Validation_Bypass_DateTime__c=1900-01-01 00:00:00, CheckVRBypassed__c=false}

10:39:24.36 (39068170)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowRecordUpdate|Update_Assignment_Closed_Withdrawn_Date_Field_To_Null|0|0

10:39:24.36 (39087746)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowRecordLookup|Retrieve_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (39098093)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowRecordLookup|Retrieve_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (39110630)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowRecordLookup|Retrieve_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (39134141)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowRecordLookup|Retrieve_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (114649399)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Retrieve_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment|

10:39:24.36 (114660375)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_DETAIL|FlowRecordLookup|Retrieve_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment|0

10:39:24.36 (114769343)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowRecordLookup|Retrieve_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment|0|75

10:39:24.36 (114792733)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_In_Progress

10:39:24.36 (114806649)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_In_Progress

10:39:24.36 (114819152)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_In_Progress

10:39:24.36 (114834320)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_In_Progress

10:39:24.36 (114898185)|FLOW_RULE_DETAIL|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_In_Progress_Yes|true|false

10:39:24.36 (114916791)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_In_Progress_Yes|true

10:39:24.36 (114964155)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowDecision|Was_Assignment_Status_Changed_to_In_Progress|0|0

10:39:24.36 (114976151)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Are_there_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (114984245)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowDecision|Are_there_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (114993115)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowDecision|Are_there_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (115007538)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowDecision|Are_there_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment

10:39:24.36 (115024474)|FLOW_RULE_DETAIL|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Are_there_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment_Yes|false|false

10:39:24.36 (115037457)|FLOW_VALUE_ASSIGNMENT|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|Are_there_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment_Yes|false

10:39:24.36 (115062744)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowDecision|Are_there_In_Progress_Tasks_for_Assignment|0|0
```

[Here are the log elements related to the "Custom Error" Element]

```
10:39:24.36 (115073473)|FLOW_ELEMENT_BEGIN|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowCustomError|Throw_Assignment_In_Progress_With_No_Tasks_Error

10:39:24.36 (115081229)|FLOW_ELEMENT_DEFERRED|FlowCustomError|Throw_Assignment_In_Progress_With_No_Tasks_Error

10:39:24.36 (115088979)|FLOW_ELEMENT_END|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|FlowCustomError|Throw_Assignment_In_Progress_With_No_Tasks_Error

10:39:24.36 (115100125)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_BEGIN|FlowCustomError|Throw_Assignment_In_Progress_With_No_Tasks_Error

10:39:24.36 (115169626)|FLOW_BULK_ELEMENT_END|FlowCustomError|Throw_Assignment_In_Progress_With_No_Tasks_Error|0|0
```

[End of log elements related to the "Custom Error" Element]

```
10:39:24.36 (115267258)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END|1

10:39:24.36 (115285093)|FLOW_INTERVIEW_FINISHED|3746993e897e4051bf8c364c05cf18c4a8ae174-5a0b|XXXX Assignment Before Update
```

I have referred to the following pages:

help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_create_custom_error_messages_in_record_triggered_flows.htm&release=246&type=5

[www.asagarwal.com/step-by-step-guide-to-custom-error-in-record-triggered-flow](http://www.asagarwal.com/step-by-step-guide-to-custom-error-in-record-triggered-flow) (I keyed in on the observations section and added an "End" element immediately after the "Custom Errors"

salesforcetime.com/2023/08/04/display-custom-error-messages-in-record-triggered-flows

[www.xtivia.com/blog/salesforce-custom-error-messages-for-record-triggered-flows](http://www.xtivia.com/blog/salesforce-custom-error-messages-for-record-triggered-flows)

[www.apexhours.com/custom-error-messages-for-record-triggered-flows](http://www.apexhours.com/custom-error-messages-for-record-triggered-flows)

automationchampion.com/2023/08/03/display-custom-error-messages-for-record-triggered-flows-2

[www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-flow-custom-error-component](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-flow-custom-error-component)

[image: Instance Information]

My issue is that while the element is executed during my "before update" flow, the error is never delivered to the screen and execution completes successfully even though it should not.  Is there something I am doing wrong with the implementation of the new "Custom Error" element or is this an issue in Salesforce?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the UX happen to be the standard UX for the record or some custom VF page or LWC?

Comment: It is a standard lightning experience record page.

Comment: Bueller?...Bueller?

Comment: did you manage to resolve the issue with custom error?

Comment: @CPQEnjoyer I think now works after the latest major release.

Comment: @throwbi-wankenobi Hi, was it a release issue? as i am facing the same problem

Comment: Everything seems to be working correctly since Spring '24 release.